# Identification of a spider

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

[image]

I have found this 8mm spider in my home, North London. I've been told it may be a false widow but wanted a second opinion.

Note: The silvery parts in the picture are actually brownish in colour

Answer (score 2):

It does appear to be a young spider, and seems consistent with a young *Steatoda* of some sort, so "False Widow" sounds OK.

Edit:  I just did a quick Google search and pulled up a useful paper (link below) that pretty clearly indicates that this is almost certainly a young *Steatoda nobilis*, one of the 'False Widows'.  See the top left - image A

[image]

[Dugon, M.M., *et al.* 2017. Occurrence, reproductive rate and identification of the non-native noble false widow spider *Steatoda nobilis* (Thorell, 1875) in Ireland. In *Biology and Environment: Proceedings of the Royal Irish Academy* 117(2):77-89](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Identifi-cation-chart-for-various-life-stages-of-Steatoda-nobilis-collected-in-Ireland_fig2_319881734)